# Issue with select using directive in angularjs http://plnkr.co/edit/atz1TBSknwEP8N0T08Q1?p=preview

Tags: angularjs, select, directive

I am facing problem to link up the some of the atrributes to select element using attribute directive,but i am getting the options repeated twice.Refer for my issue: Please check the plnkr in title,I am not able to add this plnkr in description

Comment: please add some code..what you have tried so far..

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this line `$compile(elem)(scope);`
You don't need to compile your element again inside the post-link function